# PureOS TP-Link WN725N RTL8188EU / BCM94312

Tags: debian, wifi, pureos

Just installed PureOS Version 3.28.2 and I'm having trouble with getting WiFi working. I have an internal BCM94312 and I also have a TP-Link WN725N V2 neither of which can I get to work. With the TP-Link, it goes fine until I tell it (as sudo) `rtl8188eu make all` and it gives me

> [Makefile:151: modules] Error 2

I can't find what to do to get around this easily.

Comment: Error 2 is "file not found", it should say in the previous messages, what it misses. I suggest include them into the question. Btw, TP-Link is mainly a router, are you trying to activate some usb wifi stick?

Comment: @peterh the WN725N V2 isn't a router.

Answer (score 2):

PureOS is a [GNU distribution](https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.en.html) based on debian, it doesn't have a *non-free* or *contrib* repository :

> These distros are ready-to-use full systems whose developers have made a commitment to follow the Guidelines for Free System Distributions. This means they will include, and propose, exclusively free software. They will reject nonfree applications, nonfree programming platforms, nonfree drivers, nonfree firmware “blobs”, nonfree games, and any other nonfree software, as well as nonfree manuals or documentation.

Realtek and Broadcom wifi cards require a `non-free` software .

You need a wifi card with chipset that work with a **free software**.

[Debian : Wifi](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi)